# Change MainWindow content from other pages

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

In my main window in WPF application I have a Badged element (from material design)

This is my code:

```
<materialDesign:Badged BadgePlacementMode="Left" 
    Name="RequestBadge" 
    Badge="3" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Content="Show Requests" ..... />
</materialDesign:Badged>
```

I want to change Badge content dynamically.

I add this function in code-behind:

```
public void setBadge(int num)
{
    RequestBadge.Badge = num;
}
```

But when I try to call this function from other pages, I get this error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property `PL.MainWindow.setBadge(int)`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to find an open instance of MainWindow:

```
var mw = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
mw?.SetBadge(counter);
```

Comment: I have an instance to main window  from the page, public  MainWindow CurrentWindow{
            get{
                return (App.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow);
            }
        } but still cannot call the method

Comment: `CurrentWindow.SetBadge(counter)`

Answer (score -2):

The fastest solution would be to use a singleton pattern to access your `MainWindow`  and with this create a static method in your `MainWindow` that sets your badge:

```
private static MainWindow _instance;

public MainWindow()
{
    _instance = this;
    ...
}

public static void SetBadge(int num)
{
    _instance.setBadge(num);
}
```

Comment: public static void setBadge(int num){
            RequestBadge.Badge = num;
        } The requestBadge (The element) not recognize in static method

Comment: Sorry, I was too quick and I've cut couple of corners with my answer. See the edited answer introducing a singleton pattern. You define a private static variable that holds the reference to MainWindow. You assign the value to this variable in your constructor. You leave your setBadge method intact and define a new one - static void SetBadge that calls on the singleton to access the setBadge.